# JSF + CSS: custom panelGroup id is overriden by UINamingContainer

Tags: css, jsf

I have html page designed with css. There are selectors for DIV and SPAN elements like this:

```
...

#gr-bg1 {
    ....
    background-color: red;
    ....
}

...
```

and create appropriate of it xhtml page with panelGroups:

```
 <h:panelGroup id="gr-bg1" styleClass="item1" layout="block">
        <h:panelGroup styleClass="item-value">
            <h:outputText value="#{i18n.rejections}"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup styleClass="num" layout="block">
            <h:outputText value="#{info.rejections}"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
 </h:panelGroup>
```

and as result have html:

```
<div id="A4405:gr-bg1" class="item1">
   <span class="item-value">text</span>
   <div class="num">34534535</div>
</div>
```

What to do if css selector looking #gr-bg1 id ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `JSF` and `CSS` a few months ago. I think I solved it reading out the Id of html-generated `tag` via Firebug and replaced the `Id` of the `CSS-sheet`.

In your case:

```
#A4405:gr-bg1 {
....
background-color: red;
.... }
```

Don't know if that is best practise, but it's kind of a workaround.

Otherwise you could prevent JSF generating own Ids like "A4405" of the element being placed one level above your div by giving the element above your own Id and using this instead.

Comment: I have tried to wrap this element by other `panelGroup` with its own `ID`, but then this new parent had the same prefix "A4405" added to `ID`.

Comment: Maybe every parent has to have an own `id`. Otherwise, jsf-frameworks gerenates an `id` for you. Did you try giving every parent an user-defined `id`?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. But this parent has only `h:view` element as its parent. And I cannot set `id` for that.

Comment: Sorry, i tried to find out my solution a few months ago, but i can't find anything. I think i used my solution above. I'm sorry.